# consume messages on fixed time interval / only one message at once

Tags: php, rabbitmq

Due to external API limitations, I want to handle messages only in a fixed time interval. Only one message at a time.

To process all messages in sequence, my code looks something like this:

```
$conn           = new AMQPConnection($rbmqHOST, $rbmqPORT, $rbmqUSER, $rbmqPASS, $rbmqVHOST);
$ch             = $conn->channel();
$ch->exchange_declare($exchange, 'direct', false, true, false);
$ch->queue_declare($queue, false, true, false, false);
$ch->queue_bind($queue, $exchange, $queue);

function process_message($msg)
{
    //do something ..

    //ack msg
    $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
}

$ch->basic_consume($queue, $queue, false, false, false, false, 'process_message');

function shutdown($ch, $conn)
{
    $ch->close();
    $conn->close();
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown', $ch, $conn);

// Loop as long as the channel has callbacks registered
while (count($ch->callbacks)) {
    $ch->wait();
}
```

Calling `sleep()` within the processing step is not working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, got it. (:

The heuristic works as follows:

1. Start the php consumer process via cronjob in the desired time interval.
2. Cancel consumer when a message has been processed.

   ```
   ...
   function process_message($msg)
   {
       //do something ..

       //ack msg
       $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
       //cancel consumer
       $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_cancel($msg->delivery_info['consumer_tag']);
   }
   ...
   ```
3. After starting a consumer process, check if another consumer process is already running. If so, break off in order to avoid several parallel processes. Just check the return values from `queue_declare()`:

   ```
   ...
   list(,,$consumerCount) = $ch->queue_declare($rbmqAmazonInit, false, true, false, false);

   if ($consumerCount >= 1) {
       //another consumer is already runing
       exit;
   }
   ...
   ```